# Specify docker engine version with docker machine

Tags: docker, boot2docker, docker-machine

`docker-machine` creates new instances with the latest docker engine version.

Is it possible to specify the docker engine version?

The `docker-machine create` command has a `--engine-install-url` option. However I was not able to find version specific URLs (https://get.docker.com/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [issue 2029](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/2029), you should use the `docker-machine create --virtualbox-boot2docker-url` option instead.

You can see an example in [issue 2195](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/2195):

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-boot2docker-url=https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/releases/download/v1.8.3/boot2docker.iso 183
```

Obviously, this would not work for more recent docker on Windows with HyperV.